# Optimizing sql double "Not in" clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following query:

```
select * from table_2 
where 
user_1 not in (select user_id from users) or 
user_2 not in (select user_id from users)
```

The problem is that it takes very long time to execute. The tables have few millions of records. Is there any optimization that I can use for the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, rewrite these as `not exists` . . . this often has better performance:

```
select t2.*
from table_2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from users u where u.user_id = t2.user_1) or 
      not exists (select 1 from users u where u.user_id = t2.user_2);
```

More importantly, create an index on `users(user_id)`, if one does not already exist.

Comment: I have a question, Increases performance if I select field to field and not t2.* ?? example: select t2.a, t2.b

Comment: @kbworkshop . . . If you are selecting the same fields, then there is no impact on performance.  Explicitly choosing the fields is recommended if you intend to reuse this query in any way (if it is going into a view, stored procedure, or job for instance).

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
select * from table_2
LEFT JOIN `users` AS u ON u.user_id = table_2.user_1
LEFT JOIN `users` AS u2 ON u2.user_id = table_2.user_2
WHERE u.user_id is NULL and u2.user_id is NULL
```

Comment: This only returns records where both user_1 AND user_2 is not defined in the users table. While the original query showed all records where either one of the users doesn't exist. Try "WHERE u.user_id IS NULL OR u2.user_id IS NULL" instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table_2 t2 
WHERE
NOT  EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM users u WHERE  u.user_id IN(t2.user_1,t2.user_2) )
```

this should perform better.

Answer (score 0):

This query will return all rows where user_1 and/or user_2 are not in the users table

```
select * from table_2 t1
where (select count(*) from users u where user_id in(t1.user_1,t1.user_2)) < 2
```